# how to pass object to ajax.error handler from action method mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my code, I want to to trigger the $ajax error handler if file doesn't exist in my uploadDocument action method. also return a JSON object.

Upload Document action method

```
public ActionResult(HttpPostedFileBase[] uploadFiles, string requestIdEncrypted, string     QuoteNoEncrypt)
{
  if (uploadFiles[0] != null && ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     // file exist all good
  }

// return an exception sending back json object 

   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Json(new { Success = false,    Error = ExceptionFlag.ServiceFail }));

}
```

Ajax Error Handler

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    error: function(data, c, d)
    {
        // get the returned json object
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .Always() callback (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { 

});
```

From jquery 1.8, success has been deprecated.  It will be replaced with done.  As the new methods now follow the promise's principle.